# hadoop fs -ls /usr/local is dealing my Hadoop installation folder as file

Tags: hadoop

I am very much new to Hadoop. Recently I installed Hadoop-2.8.0 with the help of the blogs on internet.

I thought everything is running fine, but today when I tried running `hadoop fs -ls /usr/local command`,
It is treating my installation folder location `/usr/local/hadoop` as a file.

I tried to check in any blogs but did not find any solutions.

Please help me out guys.

Attached is the snapshot of the error I am facing.

```
 17/06/26 22:53:07 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 Root supergroup          0 2017-06-25 19:05 /usr/local/hadoop
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not. It is just showing the directories inside '/usr/local', which is rightly 'hadoop'. That is the functionality of ls command, which is to show all files and/or directories inside a given path(in your case /usr/local). So, I believe it is showing correct.